# Abel summability under the hypothesis $a_n \ge 0$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $f(x) = \sum a_nx^n$, with $a_n \ge 0$, have radius of convergence $1$.  Show that if $\lim_{x \to 1^-} f(x) = \sigma$, then $\sum a_n$ converges and $\sigma = \sum a_n$.  This is Abel summability with the hypothesis that $a_n \ge 0$.

I'm not sure how to proceed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We don't need Abel's theorem here, since we have an ebarrassment of riches. For any $N$ we have

$$ \sum_{n=1}^{N}a_nx^n \le \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_nx^n $$

for $0< x < 1.$ Taking limits as $x \to 1^-$ above gives $\sum_{n=1}^{N}a_n \le \sigma.$ Since $N$ is arbitrary, we have

$$\tag 1 \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n \le \sigma.$$

On the other hand we clearly have, for $0<x<1,$

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_nx^n \le \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n.$$

Taking the limit as $x\to 1^-$ then shows

$$\tag 2 \sigma \le \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n.$$

The inequalities $(1)$ and $(2)$ give the result.

Comment: Thank you.  This is what I was looking for.

Comment: That'll teach me to say the first thing that pops into my head...

Answer (score 0):

Presumably you know the converse: If $\sum a_n=a$, with no restrictions on $a_n$, then $\lim_{x\to1}f(x)=a$. That's Abel's theorem.

Results saying $\lim f(x)=a$, with some restrictions on $a_n$, imply $\sum a_n=1$ are "tauberian" theorems. This one, assuming $a_n\ge0$, is a fairly simple one. Because $a_n\ge0$ implies that $\sum a_n$ *exists*; now if $\sum a_n=b$ then Abel's Theorem shows that $\lim f(x)=b$.

(To make that completely correct we need Abel's Theorem in the case $a_n\ge0$ and $\sum a_n=\infty$. But that follows by very much the same proof as the version for $\sum a_n=a\in\Bbb R$.)

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  I'm not sure how to show that $\sum a_n$ is bounded given that $\lim_{x\to1^-}f(x)= \sigma$.

Comment: You don't have to show that! At least not directly. There exists $b\in[0,\infty]$ with $\sum a_n=b$. It follows from Abel's Theorem that $\lim f(x)=b$. But you're given that $\lim  f(x)=a$. So $b=a$. So $\sum a_n=a$.

Comment: In case it's caused any confusion, note that I've been reading your $\sigma$ as $a$. Old eyes...

Comment: Thank you for your explanations.  Now I need to convince myself that if $\sum a_n=\infty$, then $\lim_{x\to1^-}f(x)= \infty$.  As stated in the text book, Abel's Theorem applies in the case that $\sum a_n$ is finite.

Comment: The proof is essentially the same for $\sum a_n=\infty$. Except of course it may look different. If $a$ is finite then "close to $a$" means "within $\epsilon$ of $a$". If $a=\infty$ then "close to $a$" means "larger than $M$", or whatever letter you like to use for something "very large" to go with $\epsilon$'s "very small". Thinking about it that way should allow you to translate the one proof into the other. (If you don't get it in say a day complain and I'll add it to the answer. Think about it first... Remember $a_n\ge0$ - will help with some technicalities)